# How can I initialize multiple players?

Tags: java, class

Good day/night. I'm making a simple game with a few of my own custom classes. I made the player class and the game works with one player. I want it to create a version where the player can enter a number and a certain amount of players with names are created. The current way I have it is similar to how the single-player mode is set up. I tried a few different ways but each way overwrote the names before the last iteration of the loop. How can I have the player add more players without losing data?

Here is my code in the main file:

```
public class WordSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Search Game! What is your name?");
     String p_name = scan.nextLine();
     player mine = new player(p_name);
     System.out.println(mine.setName(p_name));
     System.out.println("Are you playing alone or with friends? Enter Yes or No!");
     String choice = scan.nextLine();

     if (choice.equals("Yes")|| choice.equals("yes")){
        System.out.println("How many people are you playing with?");
        int num_of_players = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_players+1; i++){
            System.out.print("Put their names in one at a time!");
            String p_name_2 = scan.nextLine();
            player friend = new player(p_name_2); //Will overwrite names
        }
     }
     else{
        System.out.println("Alrighty! Let's continue!");
     }
     System.out.println("Which board would you like to play?");
     String b_name = scan.nextLine();

     GameBoardClass playGame = new GameBoardClass(b_name);
     String[][] for_game = playGame.boardCreator(b_name);
    /*
     for(int i = 0; i < for_game.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< for_game[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println(for_game[i][j] + " ");
        }
     }
    */

     System.out.println(playGame.displayBoard(for_game));
     System.out.println("The game is ON!");
     playGame.playerTurn();
```

Answer (score 1):

OK.  So if you want your game to support multiple players, it is not sufficient to just create multiple `player` objects.  You *also* need to put them somewhere ... so that you can use them later.  (You could use an array, a `List`, a `Map` ... and possibly other things, depending on how you intend to use them.)

What you have so far is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_players+1; i++){
        System.out.print("Put their names in one at a time!");
        String p_name_2 = scan.nextLine();
        player friend = new player(p_name_2); //Will overwrite names
    }
```

The problem is that `friend` is a local variable.  And since it is declared inside the block of that `for` loop, the variable is going to:

1. be redeclared for each loop iteration, and
2. go out of scope (i.e. go away) when the loop ends.

And besides since the type of `friend` is `player`, it can only hold a reference to one `player` object at a time.

So you need to:

1. Move the declaration out of the loop.
2. Pick a type (see above!) that can represent / hold a collection of `player` object references.
3. Add the `player` instances to that collection.

Note: I have not written code for you.  Your learning experience should include learning to weigh up the different ways of doing things, selecting one, and translating that into code.

---

P.S.  Change the class name `player` to `Player`.  A class name should always start with an uppercase letter.  This is standard Java style.

Answer (score 0):

I think to fix that you should create an array or ArrayList of type player so that you have a place to store their names. Every time the loop iterates the previous object gets overwritten and is lost since you are not storing it anywhere.